# xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely Error 256 (driver return code) generating output

Tags: xetex, auctex, xdvipdfmx

I try to set up auctex. It basically works now and I can compile and view simple files from within emacs. But there is one file working with includes that gives me:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: File ended prematurely


No output PDF file written.
(see the transcript file for additional information)
```

There are no other error messages. auctex calls `xelatex  -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode check-gt.tex`.

This works without problems from the shell but fails from within emacs. Any ideas what to do about this?

Edit 1:

I could track it down to one package. The package for barcodes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(4.1,1in)
        \psbarcode[transx=.4,transy=.3]{978-3-96110-202-0}{includetext height=.7}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This compiles with xelatex in the shell but causes trouble in auctex.

Comment: Can you add code for a small file that shows this issue to your question?

Comment: I edited the file.